# Python random variable not working

Tags: python

Im creating a text based game and I want to implement a fallout 4 'wasteland' system. I figured that a good way to keep everything random was to make a `random.randint(1,10)` function and some if statements for every number that comes out. The problem is that when I randomise the variable, the number stays the same. Here's my code(here is a test sample of my programme thought I wouldnt need all of it):

```
import random

def randomA():
    return random.randrange(1,5)

global rollA
rollA = randomA()
alive = True
while alive == True:
    p = input("Type w")
rollA

if p == "w":     
    print(rollA)
```

Comment: Your code is not explicit. I try to correct it, but I don't know what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rollA` is a simple variable that is assigned the value *returned* from your `randomA()` function. `rollA` is *not* a callable function that returns a new random number, if that is what you were expecting.

Because of this `rollA` is never assigned another value, hence the value of `rollA` does not change.

I think that you mean to reassign to `rollA` in your loop by calling `randomA()`:

```
while alive == True:
    p = input("Type w")
    rollA = randomA()
    if p == "w":
        print(rollA)
```

A couple of other things:

- `rollA` does not need to be a global variable as it is never accessed
  within a local scope.
- Rather than `while alive == True:` you can more simply write

  ```
  while alive:
      ...
  ```
- You don't show it here, but is there an option to set `alive = False`
  in the body of your loop? If not you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Python module works fine. Your implementation is wrong. You should really read the documentations. But here is an example:

```
from random import randint

randomA = lambda x: randint(1, x)


while True:
    num = randomA(10)
    if num != 4:
        print(num)
    else:
        break
```

Displays:

```
6
6
2
6
8
5
```

Also, your code is not written in accordance with, or anything close to, Python best practices convention, aka. PEP-8. Please consider following the convention, it will help!

Finally, I don't understand the reason why you're using a `global` variable to hold a randomised number! Bad idea!

Comment: Thanks! I'm relatively new to Python so I don't know what PEP means or anything. i havnt looked at the documentation either thanks again!